# Difference between string.indexOf() and string.lastIndexOf()?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between `string.indexOf()` and `string.lastIndexOf()` in JavaScript?

```
var temp = state.indexOf("tmp");    
var temp = state.lastIndexOf("tmp");
```

Comment: Is there something in [the](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) that you're unclear about?

Comment: I have this question, but I don't get it, why stackoverflow members down vote me on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From MDN :

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, The lastIndexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the last occurrence of the specified value

So the `indexOf` will return first occurrence of the value and the `lastIndexOf` will return the last occurence of the value.

Example (copied from MDN):

```
var anyString = "Brave new world";
var a = anyString.indexOf("w")); // result = 8
var b = anyString.lastIndexOf("w")); // result 10
```

Both of the method return -1 if the value is not found

More :

- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Answer (score 5):

string.indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

string.lastIndexOf() method returns the position of the last occurrence of a specified value in a string.

Answer (score 4):

The lastIndexOf() method returns the position of the last occurrence of a specified value in a string, where as indexOf() returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

In the following example:

```
 function myFunction() {
     var str = "Hello planet earth, you are a great planet.";
     var n = str.lastIndexOf("planet");
     var n2 = str.indexOf("planet");

 }
```

`n` will return 36
and `n2` will return 6

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 3):

[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function is match first occurance, [`LastindexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) function is match last occurance

Both function are using for finding index in **String** or **Array**;

sample code with `String` operation

```
var state = "abcdtmpefgtmp";
var temp =state.indexOf("tmp"); //match first occurance
console.log(temp);
//>4

var temp =state.lastIndexOf("tmp"); //match last occurance
console.log(temp);
//>10
```

sample code with `Array` operation

```
var state = ["abc", "tmp", "efg", "tmp"];
var temp =state.indexOf("tmp");
console.log(temp);
//>1
var temp = state.lastIndexOf("tmp");
console.log(temp);
//>3
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `indexOf` & `lastIndexOf` are native javascript functions. Both functions can be applied on `Strings` as well as `Arrays`.

The `indexOf` return the very first index where the element matched.

On the other hand `lastIndexOf` returns the last index where the element matched.

```
"myname".indexOf('m') //returns 0

"myname".lastIndexOf('m') //returns 4
```

Comment: They're *not* pure JavaScript functions, but native functions.

Comment: A pure JavaScript function is an implementation in JavaScript itself :)